# ionic datetime picker opentable style

Tags: ionic-framework, datetimepicker

I am using ionic to build a mobile application and I want to use a datetime picker like to "OpenTable" app. I inserted the image of the control.

[image]

Is there some kind of library to make my datetime picker similar to that ? Or is there easier way to build that ?

Comment: You're going to have to write a custom plugin for that. You can fork https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker as it provides a good base and add the necessary code for Android/iOS for what you need.